# How can I implement a Java 8 interface but run on Java 6?

Tags: java, java-8

I have an library, [Fakir](http://github.com/dmcg/fakir) seeing as you ask, that I would like to keep compatible with Java 6. At the same time it would be really nice if its key abstraction, the [Faker](https://github.com/dmcg/fakir/blob/master/src/main/java/com/oneeyedmen/fakir/Faker.java), was to be able to implement `java.util.function.Supplier<T>`.

I've fudged things by implementing my own copy of Supplier, so that at least lambdas can be used, but short of shipping two different jar files (ah Scala, how I miss your multiple versions for different language specs) is there any way to have my key abstraction forward compatible?

Comment: You need something similar like retrolambda.

Comment: As I read it, my clients on Java 6 would need retrolambda, not me?

Comment: Even if you don't implement `Supplier`, it's easy enough to use an instance of your class as a `Supplier` using method references, e.g. `Supplier<T> sup = faker::get;`.

Comment: That's a good point fabian. The trouble is that I want to accept a Supplier in one place as well, although I suppose that the same trick will work in reverse

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible. At some point, you need to make a leap, and your library no longer works with pre-8 java. You could do it now with pro and cons; cons being there's not many programmer familiar with java8 at this time yet.

There are some new features in Java8, like lambda, default method, static interface method, new type inference system, new utilities like Stream, that will have a big impact on how APIs are designed; they are not available to older java; and keeping compatible with older java is a handcuff to the API designers.

The pro with jumping on Java8 wagon now is that your API would be more modern, without the baggage of older java. This will pay off in the (not-very-far) future.

Comment: Perhaps a closer look at the changes of the future Java 9 release may also help for deciding when to "cut off" the old Java versions. Personally I would wait until Java 9 since there will be some bigger changes due to the module concept.

Comment: @mschenk74 - well Java8 has a lot to digest, so it's better to start early. I don't think java9 will have too much impact on API design though.

Comment: Since java9 will probably break many old code that uses internal-APIs that will be no longer accessible there will be changes I bet. It depends on the type of library one is providing: if it is a stable and complete long-term library than it probably makes sense to wait until there is no other way but if it is a dynamic library that has to react on current ideas and problems than it is better to switch to java 8 as soon as possible.

Comment: Actually the API is just fine with Java 6, it's just that I'd like to be forward compatible via actual interfaces if possible.

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor - It's fine to define your own functional interface. But it's bad to use the same name as JDK's (future or current). It's annoying to the user, as it's very easy to import the wrong one, and then it's perplexing why it doesn't compile.

Comment: @bayou.io: I disagree. If the interface is a mirror of another, using the same name is fine. Especially as you don’t need to import the interface in Java 8 when implementing it via lambda expression or method reference.

Comment: @Holger - yes, in java8 we don't need to mention the interface name as much. Nevertheless, sometimes we do in the user code, e.g. we might need `Supplier` local variable, instance variable, or method parameter. Accidentally importing the wrong one is annoying at the least.

Comment: @Holger - if the name of the functional interface  indeed does not matter to your user code, it's more the reason to come up with a different name.

Answer (score 1):

As `java.util.function` only includes functional interfaces you can use a "backport" of it. The backport could of course not provide the default functions, only define the interfaces, but the interfaces are all you need to add compatability with Java 8.

[streamsupport](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.sourceforge.streamsupport%7Cstreamsupport%7C1.2.1%7Cjar) is a backport that adds quite a bit more than just the interfaces, but it avoids name clashing and should not require you to do two separate releases.

To use this method, if you use streamsupport, just write

```
import java8.util.function.*;
```

instead of

```
import java.util.function.*;
```

Edit: [mmm-util-backport-java.util.function](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.sf.m-m-m%7Cmmm-util-backport-java.util.function%7C1.0.1%7Cjar) requires use of `-Xclassbootpath` as it defines `java.util.function` instead of the same thing with a different name, so streamsupport is the better option.

Answer (score 0):

**Fail on my part - this doesn't work for 'java.' packages**

One **dirty** trick would be to provide the Supplier interface, as defined in Java 8, so you'd be shipping a 'java.util.function.Supplier'.

If the client is not pre-Java 8, then this can satsify dependancies in your implementation.

When the client is on Java 8, then the JRE jars take precedence over the classpath and the "real" implementation will be used.

If it was more than an interface you where stubbing, then I'd be tempted to make the placeholder class throw an error if it was ever used.

You would need to test for package sealing on pre-Java 8 JREs though.  I don't think that this is the case.

I've seen this approach happen by accident in some large projects, where jars have been added containing 'java.*' or 'javax.*' packages prior to them being incorporated into the JRE (eg JSR jars). These have run happly long after the functionality was part of the JRE.

**Update:**

As noted below, the class loader baulks on non-JRE 'java.*' packages, so I must be misremembering the legacy debris (unless the rule was not inforced before 1.3/1.4?).

Perhaps some messy work with 'java.lang.reflect.Proxy' might achieve results - but hardly a transparent solution.

Comment: Application class loaders are not allowed to define classes whose name starts with `java.`. Seems you are confusing it with the `javax.` prefix. These two different prefixes exist for exactly that reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any other way than ship 2 versions of the library.

I see you use maven. You could play with dependency management and have 3 projects just like this:

- **fakir-common**: (in Java 6)
- **fakir-java8**: (in Java 8, depends on fakir-common)
- **fakir-java6**: (in Java 6, depends on fakir-common)

Make the most of your code that don't require to use the Supplier interface in the *fakir-common* part.

Then implement the Supplier specific aspects in the two other parts.

You could use the [streamsupport](http://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/) project as a dependency for *fakir-java6*:

> streamsupport is a backport of the Java 8 java.util.function (functional
>   interfaces) and java.util.stream (streams) API for users of Java 6 or
>   7

Thanks to it, the two fakir-javaN projects will have almost the same code.
It may be even possible to use code generation to write it only once.

Comment: Shipping two different versions of the library is exactly what the questioner wants to avoid.

Comment: Actually, streamsupport does not seem to require shipping two different versions. It avoids name clashing.

Comment: @Holger, You are right. However, I wanted to provide an alternative to the "it's not possible" answer with which I agree.